# How to assign the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, delegates, xamarin.ios

I try to use the `UIPopoverPresentationController`. For the presenting I need to assign the delegate (`UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`) to be able to use methods like `prepareForPopoverPresentation`, 
`popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` and so on.

If assign a view controller to the delegate property I get

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'UIKit.UIViewController' to 'UIKit.IUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So what are my options here? In the native world one could add the required protocoll, but you can't do that in Xamarin. I want that the view controller which is presented in the popover gets the notification (prepare, did dismiss, ...). How can I do that?

Of course I could create a new instance of `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and assign it, but then I would have connect the delegate with the view controller somehow (e.g. through events). Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It looks like Xamarin has not exposed a `WeakDelegate` property and has also made the delegate class the abstract class for the protocol and not the interface. In this scenario - you will have to create another class that implements the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and another for the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`.

In the future, it's worth noting that there is often a `WeakDelegate` property (along with `Delegate`) which allows assigning any class to the delegate and implementing the protocol implicitly through `ExportAttribute` on the protocol methods. Xamarin also sometimes uses the protocol's matching interface (such as `IUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`) instead of the matching abstract class (the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` class).

---

**Mostly incorrect original answer**

It should be possible for your `UIViewController` class to implement the `IUIPopoverControllerDelegate` and implement any methods that you need. Usually iOS protocols get converted into an interface for Xamarin.iOS and you can find it by appending an "I" to the protocol name.

```
public class TestVC : UIViewController, IUIPopoverControllerDelegate
{
    public override UIPopoverPresentationController PopoverPresentationController {
        get {
            return base.PopoverPresentationController;
        }
    }

    [Export ("popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:")]
    public void DidDismiss (UIPopoverController popoverController)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

Here is an example where I've implemented a few of the popover methods. I hope this helps. I haven't explicitly tested this, but I think it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for showing this way of implementing. `DidDismiss` should be `public void DidDismiss(UIPopoverPresentationController popoverPresentationController)` to accomodate for `UIPopoverPresentationController` and the interface should be `IUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`. One issue still remains for me: The assignment of `popController.Delegate = someUIViewController;` fails because I pass the general type `UIViewController` and not `TestVC`. What can I do in such a situation? Casting seems not be possible.

Comment: If your view controller instance implements the requested interface, then casting shouldn't cause any issues. You can check that `(IUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate)someUIViewController` does not throw a cast exception. If it does throw an exception, then your view controller isn't implementing the interface you need.

Comment: OK, then it's because I have some wrapper class build around and I'm not using `TestVC`, but `UIViewController` in general. It doesn't compile, because the compiler doesn't know that the `UIViewController` type can implement the interface. It would work if I don't use `UIViewController`. Is there a way to get this working e.g. with `object` or so? All I want is to store a variable, which is automatically set to *true* in `PrepareForPopoverPresentation` and set to *false* in `DidDismissPopover`.

Comment: Now I tried to assign a `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` property the *this* value (`public class TestVC : UIViewController, IUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`), but here I also get the compilation error: *Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestVC' to 'UIKit.UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate'*.

Comment: Can you post all of the code for defining `TestVC` class and the code where you assign the delegate? I'm not really sure what's going on, but I need to see the code to help.

Comment: No problem, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/da4o8m5s1tdwk1u/TestPopoverPresentation.zip?dl=0) is my test project. As you can see I want to combine `UIPopoverPresentationController` and `UIPopoverController`. The boolean variable is called `IsInPopover` and I want to know in `ContentViewController` if it is in a popover or not (I know there is a method for detecting this but only for iOS 8 and above). I tried multiple approaches so I hope you understand what I'm doing here.

Comment: **It looks like I was wrong here** - Xamarin.iOS normally has a weak delegate variation that lets you use the interfaces and/or `ExportAttribute` but it looks like the delegates you need are not available in that way. You will need to subclass the abstract classes `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` because you need to use those abstract classes in the inheritance hierarchy to be able to assign the delegate properties.

Comment: Perhaps you could integrate your last comment into your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the following:

I subclassed `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and here I defined the events `PrepareForPopover` and `DidDismiss`. So I overwrote `PrepareForPopoverPresentation` and `DidDismissPopover` and I throw the belonging events.

Then I assigned this delegate to my `UIPopoverPresentationController` instance. Through subscribing to the events of my custom delegate I was able to get notified, when the popover is displayed and when it is dismissed. Casting is not possible (as I tried in my question).

With this one can set some variables or call some methods from the view controller, which is presented in the popover.